# In Triggers Getting Error Invalid loop variable type

Tags: trigger, after-trigger

Iam trying to update the `CTSRecrutingApp__Warranty__c` field in `CTSRecrutingApp__Bill__c` custom object depending on other custom object field `CTSRecrutingApp__Warranty__c` in `CTSRecrutingApp__Booking_Details__c` custom object. There is a Lookup Relation(`CTSRecrutingApp__Booking_Details__c` as parent) exist between these two custom objects.

But Iam getting an error showing that:

> Invalid loop variable type expected
> CTSRecrutingApp__Booking_Details__c was CTSRecrutingApp__Bill__c.

And my code is given below:

```
trigger WarrantyField on CTSRecrutingApp__Booking_Details__c (after insert,after update) {
    string name;
    for(CTSRecrutingApp__Booking_Details__c b:Trigger.new){
        if(b.CTSRecrutingApp__Warranty__c != null)
        {
            name=b.CTSRecrutingApp__Warranty__c; 
        }
    }
    for(CTSRecrutingApp__Bill__c w:Trigger.new){
        if(w.CTSRecrutingApp__Warranty__c != name){
           w.CTSRecrutingApp__Warranty__c = name;
        }
    update w;
    }
}
```

If possible please write the code with the help of the trigger handler.

Comment: You should tackle things one at a time. First, work on fixing the code in your trigger. After you have a working trigger, then you can focus on using a trigger framework (and you should do research on frameworks and make an honest attempt on your own for that. "Do my work for me" questions tend to be downvoted and closed).

Answer (score 1):

`Trigger.new` in your trigger is a list of `CTSRecrutingApp__Booking_Details__c`,. but not `CTSRecrutingApp__Bill__c`

at the same time you have the following lines of code: `for(CTSRecrutingApp__Booking_Details__c b:Trigger.new){` and `for(CTSRecrutingApp__Bill__c w:Trigger.new){`

---

You'll need to follow sfdcdox's [The Aggregate Query Update Pattern](https://sfdcfox.blogspot.com/2017/03/the-aggregate-query-update-pattern.html) in order to achieve the desired functionality.

Comment: Can You Please write or copy the answer that you want to tell.

Comment: @UmaMahesh This site isn't a free coding service, or meant to be a place where you can simply copy/paste solutions. The goal here is to help solve problems and help you learn how to avoid similar things in the future. There is an expectation that you will make an honest attempt to read, learn, and apply this information on your own.